# curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) -

Tags: curl, kubectl

I am experiencing an issue on my Windows laptop with the following curl command:

```
curl.exe -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/v1.28.4/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe"
```

Encountering error (35) with the message: "schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate."

Any insights or solutions to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! #Windows #Curl #ErrorResolution #TechSupport